# Installing company app and application enrollment token through company portal. IE 10 in wp8 freezes in tap to open

Tags: windows-phone-8

We are distributing the company app and application enrollment token through our company portal. We observe the following behavior. When the user downloads the AETX through the IE 10 that comes with Windows phone 8 there is a prompt that comes as "tap to install", then a prompt to install the certificate automatically appears. After installing the certificate the IE browser tab just stays there. It does not move to my original web site.

We tried to perform the action on the page using various standard technique like loading the content in a Iframe and opening a windows etc. But apparently we see that whether we try to open it in IFRAME or new windows, the download link for ATEX and XAP opens in the same. It does not eve create a new tab/page.

Every time the user has to click the back button after install to reach the main site. This is very annoying for users.

Any help/suggestion would be of immense help

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you 3 checklists:-

1. Its recommended by the Wp8 enrollment Application file download should not be coming as "chunked" in HTTP protocol. Please ensure it comes in one piece.
2. Try serving the XAP file without any Content-Type header (which by default is set to octet stream usually on the server end).
3. Try pushing your Enterprise app during the enrollment phase itself to avoid these complications. Its the best way to install the company app as a last step in the WAP Provisioning.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestion. I believe that is a default behavior of  IE on WP8. I used this plug in to schedule the download one after another
http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/